# Is there a way to link several if statements in Python so that they all run simultaneously?

Tags: python

I need to write a program that replaces characters in a string, I need to do it without using replace(). This is not a problem as translate() works just fine. However, I need to replace multiple characters and right now, I can only replace one at a time, as in only one of the 'if' statements runs. It looks somewhat like this:

```
#constants
X = 'xex' 
Z = 'zaz'
    
#then the user provides a string using input() 

def newest_string():

    for i in string:

        if i == 'x':
            new_word = word.translate({ord(i): X for i in 'x'})
            continue
        elif i == 'z':
            new_word = word.translate({ord(i): Z for i in 'z'})
            continue

         #then there are many more similar statements using translate() because 
           there are many characters that need to be changed

        else:
             continue

    return string
```

Note that `str.translate` converts all occurrences of the specified characters, so the `for` loop is just a waste of efficiency.

Also, `{ord(i): X for i in 'x'}` and `{ord(i): Z for i in 'z'}` are the exact equivalent of `{ord('x'): X}` and `{ord('z'): X}`, as there is only one character both `'x'` and `'z'`.

Comment: Is `for i in 'x'` supposed to be `for i in x` (no quote)? As it is you always get `'x'` there once.

Comment: Does it make sense to build a dictionary out of the translations, `{"x": "xex", "z": "zaz"}`?  Then you can loop through that dictionary and apply them one at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you can use a `dict()` with more than one conversion:

```
#constants
X = 'xex' 
Z = 'zaz'
    
#then the user provides a string using input() 
def newest_string(word):
    new_word = word.translate({ord('x'): X, ord('z'): Z})
    return new_word

print(newest_string('I am at the zoo. So exciting!'))
```

Output:

```
I am at the zazoo. So exexciting!
```

Comment: @kabanus Got it!

Comment: @kabanus thanks! i think i do actually need to translate all occurrences of the keys, so it works for me.

Comment: @riya_m35 That's what I meant. Don't forget to upvote this answer if you found it helpful and accept it if it solved your problem. Good luck!